# error: (1098) conflicting declarations for variable "_sprintf" in XC8

Tags: c, embedded, mplab, xc8

I want to append the length (integer) of a string message to another string using sprintf. But every time i get the above error.

```
void ClientToServer(const char *client_msg)
{
    char str_len[20];
    int len = strlen(client_msg);
    char *ptr;
    sprintf(ptr,"AT+CIPSEND=0,%d",len);

}
```

**Full error:**

```
CLEAN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 77ms)
make -f nbproject/Makefile-default.mk SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/acer kuttan/Documents/pk/pk/TokenOverWiFi'
make  -f nbproject/Makefile-default.mk dist/default/production/TokenOverWiFi.production.hex
make[2]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/acer kuttan/Documents/pk/pk/TokenOverWiFi'
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\xc8\v2.10\bin\xc8-cc.exe"  -mcpu=18F25K80 -c  -fshort-double -fshort-float -memi=wordwrite -O1 -fasmfile -maddrqual=ignore -xassembler-with-cpp -mwarn=-3 -Wa,-a -DXPRJ_default=default  -msummary=-psect,-class,+mem,-hex,-file  -ginhx032 -Wl,--data-init -mno-keep-startup -mno-download -mdefault-config-bits   -std=c90 -gdwarf-3 -mstack=compiled:auto:auto:auto     -o build/default/production/TokMain.p1 TokMain.c 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\xc8\v2.10\bin\xc8-cc.exe"  -mcpu=18F25K80 -c  -fshort-double -fshort-float -memi=wordwrite -O1 -fasmfile -maddrqual=ignore -xassembler-with-cpp -mwarn=-3 -Wa,-a -DXPRJ_default=default  -msummary=-psect,-class,+mem,-hex,-file  -ginhx032 -Wl,--data-init -mno-keep-startup -mno-download -mdefault-config-bits   -std=c90 -gdwarf-3 -mstack=compiled:auto:auto:auto     -o build/default/production/TokenTimer.p1 TokenTimer.c 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\xc8\v2.10\bin\xc8-cc.exe"  -mcpu=18F25K80 -c  -fshort-double -fshort-float -memi=wordwrite -O1 -fasmfile -maddrqual=ignore -xassembler-with-cpp -mwarn=-3 -Wa,-a -DXPRJ_default=default  -msummary=-psect,-class,+mem,-hex,-file  -ginhx032 -Wl,--data-init -mno-keep-startup -mno-download -mdefault-config-bits   -std=c90 -gdwarf-3 -mstack=compiled:auto:auto:auto     -o build/default/production/TokenWifi.p1 TokenWifi.c 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\xc8\v2.10\bin\xc8-cc.exe"  -mcpu=18F25K80 -c  -fshort-double -fshort-float -memi=wordwrite -O1 -fasmfile -maddrqual=ignore -xassembler-with-cpp -mwarn=-3 -Wa,-a -DXPRJ_default=default  -msummary=-psect,-class,+mem,-hex,-file  -ginhx032 -Wl,--data-init -mno-keep-startup -mno-download -mdefault-config-bits   -std=c90 -gdwarf-3 -mstack=compiled:auto:auto:auto     -o build/default/production/WifiCom.p1 WifiCom.c 
WifiCom.c:24:1: warning: (361) function declared implicit int
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\xc8\v2.10\bin\xc8-cc.exe"  -mcpu=18F25K80 -Wl,-Map=dist/default/production/TokenOverWiFi.production.map  -DXPRJ_default=default  -Wl,--defsym=__MPLAB_BUILD=1  -fshort-double -fshort-float -memi=wordwrite -O1 -fasmfile -maddrqual=ignore -xassembler-with-cpp -mwarn=-3 -Wa,-a -msummary=-psect,-class,+mem,-hex,-file  -ginhx032 -Wl,--data-init -mno-keep-startup -mno-download -mdefault-config-bits -std=c90 -gdwarf-3 -mstack=compiled:auto:auto:auto      -Wl,--memorysummary,dist/default/production/memoryfile.xml -o dist/default/production/TokenOverWiFi.production.elf  build/default/production/TokMain.p1 build/default/production/TokenTimer.p1 build/default/production/TokenWifi.p1 build/default/production/WifiCom.p1     
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\xc8\v2.10\pic\sources\c90\common\sprintf.c:13:: error: (1098) conflicting declarations for variable "_sprintf" (WifiCom.c:24)
(908) exit status = 1
make[2]: *** [dist/default/production/TokenOverWiFi.production.hex] Error 1
nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:186: recipe for target 'dist/default/production/TokenOverWiFi.production.hex' failed
make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/acer kuttan/Documents/pk/pk/TokenOverWiFi'
nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:91: recipe for target '.build-conf' failed
make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/acer kuttan/Documents/pk/pk/TokenOverWiFi'
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target '.build-impl' failed
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 7s)
```

**Edit: Warnings**

The error vanished with couple of warnings when added stdio.h to the top of all header file.

```
CLEAN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 49ms) make -f nbproject/Makefile-default.mk SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/acer kuttan/Documents/pk/pk/TokenOverWiFi' make  -f nbproject/Makefile-default.mk dist/default/production/TokenOverWiFi.production.hex make[2]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/acer kuttan/Documents/pk/pk/TokenOverWiFi' "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\xc8\v2.10\bin\xc8-cc.exe" 
-mcpu=18F25K80 -c  -fshort-double -fshort-float -memi=wordwrite -O1 -fasmfile -maddrqual=ignore -xassembler-with-cpp -mwarn=-3 -Wa,-a -DXPRJ_default=default  -msummary=-psect,-class,+mem,-hex,-file  -ginhx032 -Wl,--data-init -mno-keep-startup -mno-download -mdefault-config-bits   -std=c90 -gdwarf-3 -mstack=compiled:auto:auto:auto     -o build/default/production/TokMain.p1 TokMain.c  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\xc8\v2.10\bin\xc8-cc.exe"  -mcpu=18F25K80 -c 
-fshort-double -fshort-float -memi=wordwrite -O1 -fasmfile -maddrqual=ignore -xassembler-with-cpp -mwarn=-3 -Wa,-a -DXPRJ_default=default  -msummary=-psect,-class,+mem,-hex,-file  -ginhx032 -Wl,--data-init -mno-keep-startup -mno-download -mdefault-config-bits   -std=c90 -gdwarf-3 -mstack=compiled:auto:auto:auto     -o build/default/production/TokenTimer.p1 TokenTimer.c  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\xc8\v2.10\bin\xc8-cc.exe"  -mcpu=18F25K80 -c 
-fshort-double -fshort-float -memi=wordwrite -O1 -fasmfile -maddrqual=ignore -xassembler-with-cpp -mwarn=-3 -Wa,-a -DXPRJ_default=default  -msummary=-psect,-class,+mem,-hex,-file  -ginhx032 -Wl,--data-init -mno-keep-startup -mno-download -mdefault-config-bits   -std=c90 -gdwarf-3 -mstack=compiled:auto:auto:auto     -o build/default/production/TokenWifi.p1 TokenWifi.c  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\xc8\v2.10\bin\xc8-cc.exe"  -mcpu=18F25K80 -c 
-fshort-double -fshort-float -memi=wordwrite -O1 -fasmfile -maddrqual=ignore -xassembler-with-cpp -mwarn=-3 -Wa,-a -DXPRJ_default=default  -msummary=-psect,-class,+mem,-hex,-file  -ginhx032 -Wl,--data-init -mno-keep-startup -mno-download -mdefault-config-bits   -std=c90 -gdwarf-3 -mstack=compiled:auto:auto:auto     -o build/default/production/WifiCom.p1 WifiCom.c  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\xc8\v2.10\bin\xc8-cc.exe"  -mcpu=18F25K80
-Wl,-Map=dist/default/production/TokenOverWiFi.production.map  -DXPRJ_default=default  -Wl,--defsym=__MPLAB_BUILD=1  -fshort-double -fshort-float -memi=wordwrite -O1 -fasmfile -maddrqual=ignore -xassembler-with-cpp -mwarn=-3 -Wa,-a -msummary=-psect,-class,+mem,-hex,-file  -ginhx032 -Wl,--data-init -mno-keep-startup -mno-download -mdefault-config-bits -std=c90 -gdwarf-3 -mstack=compiled:auto:auto:auto      -Wl,--memorysummary,dist/default/production/memoryfile.xml -o dist/default/production/TokenOverWiFi.production.elf  build/default/production/TokMain.p1 build/default/production/TokenTimer.p1 build/default/production/TokenWifi.p1 build/default/production/WifiCom.p1      WifiCom.c:25:: warning: (1257) local variable "_ptr" is used but never given a value C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\xc8\v2.10\pic\sources\c90\common\doprnt.c:558:: warning: (1498) pointer (sprintf@sp) in expression may have no targets C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\xc8\v2.10\pic\sources\c90\common\doprnt.c:1465:: warning: (1498) pointer (sprintf@sp) in expression may have no targets C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\xc8\v2.10\pic\sources\c90\common\doprnt.c:1550:: warning: (1498) pointer (sprintf@sp) in expression may have no targets C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\xc8\v2.10\pic\sources\c90\common\doprnt.c:1564:: warning: (1498) pointer (sprintf@sp) in expression may have no targets ::: warning: (1311) missing configuration setting for config word 0x300003; using default

Memory Summary:
    Program space        used   89Ah (  2202) of  8000h bytes   (  6.7%)
    Data space           used   229h (   553) of   E41h bytes   ( 15.2%)
    Configuration bits   used     7h (     7) of     7h words   (100.0%)
    EEPROM space         used     0h (     0) of   400h bytes   (  0.0%)
    ID Location space    used     8h (     8) of     8h bytes   (100.0%)
    Data stack space     used     0h (     0) of   B41h bytes   (  0.0%)

make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/acer kuttan/Documents/pk/pk/TokenOverWiFi' make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/acer kuttan/Documents/pk/pk/TokenOverWiFi'

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 9s) Loading code from C:/Users/acer kuttan/Documents/pk/pk/TokenOverWiFi/dist/default/production/TokenOverWiFi.production.hex... Loading completed
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but think about the code you have... You have a pointer `ptr`, but *where does it point?* Are you supposed to print to `str_len`?

Comment: Did you include `stdio.h` before first usage of `*printf` functions? Did you by any change declare anywhere `_sprintf` as a variable or function in your code? What is at `WifiCom.c:24`, which line is it? What are the 24 lines in WifiCom.c?

Comment: Show us that line: `WifiCom.c:24:1: warning: (361) function declared implicit int`. It might be related.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ptr doesn't point to anywhere. Its a a pointer to hold the final appended string.

Comment: @KamilCuk No, I hanent used any stdio.h in my code. I havent declared _sprintf as a variable or function in my code. The 24 line in Wificom.c is sprintf(ptr,"AT+CIPSEND=0,%d",len);

Comment: @Jabberwocky The error points to sprintf(ptr,"AT+CIPSEND=0,%d",len);

Comment: @PraveenKumarPS then just add `#include <stdio.h>` somewhere at the beginning of  Wificom.c. The actual error is this: `warning: (361) function declared implicit int`. Each time you see a warning containing the word _implicit_, consider it as an error and fix that first.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I added stdio.h exactly as you have said. but new warnings pop up. I have updated  my post. plz have a look.

Comment: `Its a a pointer to hold the final appended string.` - a pointer can't hold a string. Memory the pointer points to can hold a string. The warning is there, because you use uninitialized pointer in your code.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPS that new warning is probably related to the fact thet `ptr` is uninitialitzed (see the first comment).

Comment: @KamilCuk I have initialized the pointer with NULL. Now every thing is fine. Thank You.

Comment: @Jabberwocky  I have initialized the pointer with NULL. Now every thing is fine. But how is my previous error related to stdio.h? I am just curious.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPS that prevents the warning, but using `sprintf` on a NULL pointer will not work during run time. You need to grasp the concept of _pointer_ before going on. Where is that `""AT+CIPSEND=0,xxxx""` string supposed to end up?

Comment: @Jabberwocky sprintf is expecting a pointer to store the base address of the appended string. Right? Where I am wrong?

Comment: @PraveenKumarPS no, read the documentation of `sprintf`. Basically `sprintf` is the same thing as `printf`, but instead of going to the terminal the output goes to a buffer you provide. You need to ask another question about that specific issue, as it is unrealated to your original question. I'm not commenting this question any further.

Comment: "ptr doesn't point to anywhere" is correct (in a way), and as it doesn't point anywhere what happens when you start writing to the memory that `ptr` is pointing?

Comment: Please provide your **current** source after you edited a lot. In does not make sense to guess what you have now. But if your question is answered, write an answer and mark it, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing a string onto a pointer that is neither initialized or has allocated memory in the heap. From the looks of your logs, it would seem you're writing the program to an embedded system of some sort which probably doesn't have any memory protection via Virtual Memory and if it does, it is probably throwing a segmentation fault.

Declare `ptr` as a character array of an arbitrary size. Given, your format string, I would say 30 would be sufficient but, you can set it to be higher if required

```
void ClientToServer(const char *client_msg)
{
    int len = strlen(client_msg);
    char ptr[30];
    sprintf(ptr,"AT+CIPSEND=0,%d",len);

}
```

In your code, ptr is probably possessing some random value and it is writing your value to some address on your system, which may not even be mapped to your instruction/data memory (especially, NULL). I have also removed the str_len array which doesn't seem to be serving any purpose.